# Hide column if field is empty table.bootstrapTable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to hide the column title: 'Nome do Beneficiário' when the field: 'NomeSocial' is null or empty.

Would you help me, please?

The table is responsive. Using Javascript and `bootstrapTable`.

```
tabela.bootstrapTable('refresh');
    var options = {
        pagination: "true",
        classes: "table",
        pageSize: 10,
        cache: false,
        pageList: "[10, 25, 50]",
        sidePagination: "server",
        url: url,
        columns: [
            {
                title: 'CPF',
                field: 'Cpf',
                align: 'center',
                valign: 'middle'
            },
            {

                title: 'Matrícula',
                field: 'Matricula',
                align: 'center',
                valign: 'middle'
            },
            {
                title: 'Nome do Beneficiário',
                field: 'Nome',
                align: 'center',
                valign: 'middle'

            },
            {
                title: 'Nome Social do Beneficiário',
                field: 'NomeSocial',
                align: 'center',
                valign: 'middle'

            },

            {
                title: 'Visualizar',
                align: 'center',
                valign: 'middle',
                formatter: visualizar
            }
        ],
        formatNoMatches: function () {
            return mensagemSemRegistro;
        }
    };

    


    tabela.bootstrapTable(options);
}
```

Comment: Hi, you mean whole column data is empty so you need to hide the other column ?